# mock.patch() Not patching function in module call, but is in test function

Tags: python, django, mocking, patch, testcase

So I am trying to mock a function and it is not being mocked in the module where it is being called, but it when called directly in the test function. I am unsure what I'm doing wrong. I use patch all the time without any problems.

So in the test I have below

```py
from unittest.mock import patch
from django.test import TestCase
from web.utils.registration import test_render_mock

class TestRenderMock(TestCase): 

    @patch("django.shortcuts.render")
    def test_render_mock(self, render_mock):
        request = self.make_request()

        # Calls render in same way in function below
        test_render_mock(request)

        from django.shortcuts import render
        r = render(request, 'c')
        print(type(r))
```

which is calling the function in the file web/utils/registration.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def test_render_mock(request):
    r = render(request, 'registration/signup_link_error.html')
    print(type(r))
```

And it isn't mocking the render call in the function *test_render_mock* but it is in the test function *test_render_mock()*. The console output is below.

```
<class 'django.http.response.HttpResponse'>
<class 'unittest.mock.MagicMock'>
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Using python version 3.8.2 and Django 3.0.5

### UPDATE

I used to use the third party library mock, but using the built in one now from tne unittest library.

now for third party library you need to define the module path where there imported like so

```py
from unittest.mock import patch
from django.test import TestCase
from web.utils.registration import test_render_mock

MODULE_TESTING: str ='...'

class TestRenderMock(TestCase): 

    @patch(f"{MODULE_TESTING}.render")
    def test_render_mock(self, render_mock):
        request = self.make_request()

        # Calls render in same way in function below
        test_render_mock(request)

        from django.shortcuts import render
        r = render(request, 'c')
        print(type(r))
```